# What am I missing in this GTK/webkit program

Tags: c, linux, webkit, gtk

I have a program that is the result of months of coding in my hands and I am getting this error whenever I alt+f4 out of the program then immediately re-launch it

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ozan@ozan-PORTEGE-R700:~/dev/alpha2$ The program 'gtk-gnash' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 202 error_code 3 request_code 12 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
The program 'gtk-gnash' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 202 error_code 3 request_code 12 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
The program 'gtk-gnash' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 198 error_code 3 request_code 12 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
The program 'gtk-gnash' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 198 error_code 3 request_code 12 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
The program 'gtk-gnash' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 198 error_code 3 request_code 12 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

This is the error message that generally appears in terminal. The program has 4 threads. I suspect them not exiting. The question is how do I make these rogue threads exit if I alt+f4 or ctrl+c out of the main thread. I get these errors all the time unless I wait for about 30 sec before re-launching. You may say just wait but I want to get this thing working. Sorry for the bother:)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the window handle has not yet been destroyed when you are trying to relaunch the program. Perhaps this link will solve your problem: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=123176